# Pergunta de confirmação antes de inserir no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a seguinte pagina de insert:

```
<?php
include("conn_sys.php");

$setor      = $_POST ["setor"]; 
$fornec     = $_POST ["fornec"];
$desc         = $_POST ["desc"];    
$id_usuario = $_POST ["id_usuario"];
$login      = $_POST ["login"];
$nome       = $_POST ["nome"];
$loja       = $_POST ["loja"];
$nivel      = $_POST ["nivel"];

$incluisol = mysql_query("INSERT INTO solicitacao(sol_id, 
                                                 sol_usu,
                                               sol_setor,
                                                sol_loja,
                                                sol_desc,
                                              sol_fornec,
                                              sol_status)
                               VALUES (               '', 
                                           '$id_usuario', 
                                                '$setor',
                                                 '$loja',
                                                 '$desc',
                                               '$fornec',
                                                    '1')") or die (mysql_error());
                 mysql_query($incluisol,$conn_sys); 

  echo "<script language='javascript'>
                window.location='solicitacoes.php';
        </script>";

?>
```

O que preciso,antes de inserir perguntar se tenho certeza ou não,caso sim,fazer o insert caso não direcionar para a  página anterior.

Segue linha do botão de envio:

```
echo"<td><center><a href='finalizar.php?id=". $row['ID'] ."&usu_id=$v_id_usuario' class='btn btn-info'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved aria-hidden='true'></span></a></center></td>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No link que vai para essa página tu cria um confirm do js

```
<a href="pagina.php?acao=inserir" onclick="return confirm('Tem certeza?')">Link</a>
```

Comment: Bom dia, o meu botão fica dentro de table e uso a seguinte linha,incluso na pergunta,quando coloco o confirm esta passando direto da mesma forma,segue a linha incluindo o confirm:  echo"<td><center><a href='finalizar.php?id=". $row['ID'] ."&usu_id=$v_id_usuario' onclick='return confirm('Tem certeza?')'  class='btn btn-info'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved aria-hidden='true'></span></a></center></td>";

Comment: Consegui,Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do Vitor André está correta, mas tens um erro de aspas/plicas no teu comentário à resposta dele.

Deverás adicionar o seguinte atributo onclick:

```
onclick="return confirm('Tem certeza?')"
```

E não

```
onclick='return confirm('Tem certeza?')'
```

Estás a quebrar o link por que não estás a alternar entre ' e "